# Bootstrap 3: Is the col-md class the best baseline to work with?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 and saw that there is a revamped grid system (col-xs, col-sm, col-md, col-lg). I can see that sometimes you will want to have a few columns when viewing a site on a mobile phone or portrait mode tablet and hence the reason why someone may want to use col-xs-2 and col-sm-2 or whatever. However, I like to keep things simple: is it best to just stick with the "col-md-x" class and design the site with that in mind? So, any device viewport smaller than 970px will stack vertically (col-md breakpoint is 969px) . Personally, I think MOST designs look ugly and cluttered when you have more than one column on pages less than 750px.

Is the "col-md-x" class is a good baseline for a responsive site? For design purposes, it seems the most manageable and easiest to work with.

Comment: I think the best answer to this question is subjective: it depends entirely on the content and layout you want. I personally use `col-sm-*` as a baseline because 768px wide inputs look like crap on a portrait tablet, for example. It depends on the content you're displaying, at the end of the day

Comment: I wonder why you think 768px wide looks like crap. That's the width we used to browse the internet with in the 90s and early 2000s.

Comment: Not the resolution itself, but things like form elements stretched full width - they're too wide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside the break point of your grids there will also be the @grid-breaking-point. At this point the b.e. the navbar collapses.

I agree with you its good idea to the set a main break point. If you don't change the @grid-breaking-point (768px) i should prefer the small grid (col-sm-*) as the basic personally.
The break point of the the small grid (col-sm-*) will be at 768px too.

Answer (score 0):

The mobile first approach guidelines are recommended these days, meaning the sm size would be the best to target at outset, expanding the content into larger sizes as you build.

This is also reflected well in CSS, defining baseline styles for small screens and adding a series of "min-width:" operators to match up to the various breakpoints (768px et al)